# Serving extensionless static files in ASP.NET MVC; getting 404s

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-routing

For whatever reason (ugh, just assume we have to), we have a JavaScript file and a CSS file without an extension in our ASP.NET MVC application. The JavaScript file is at path `~/Scripts/js` and the CSS file is at `~/Styles/css`. These are static files containing JS and CSS respectively, but without file extensions.

Right now, when I try to load the resources in a browser, I get a 404 for those two paths. What do I need to do to make my ASP.NET MVC application serve these extensionless files (and serve them with the correct MIME types)? Something in the web.config and mapping a particular URL pattern to the HTTP handler for static files, I'm guessing. Apparently my Googling skills are inadequate—forgive me.

Comment: Are you using bundling and minification?

Comment: For what it's worth, extensionless URIs are processed by the ASP.NET MVC routing framework, which is why you're getting 404s: there's no route/action to respond to that particular request URL.

Comment: Extending Chris Pratt's answer, I think you're going to have a hard time getting IIS to serve these correctly. You could, alternatively, create controller actions that stream the content from disk to the response, setting content type accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think esmoore68 probably has the best answer... but...  if you don't want to do that, I wonder if you could declare the style (and the script) on the page (rather than reference the files), and maybe use labels on the pages where you need these, and actually open the files in code-behind, read them as text, then write them into the labels on the page load?

I haven't tried anything like that, specifically, but it seems like it would work.

If it does, maybe you could create a user control so you can just put that in all the pages, rather than repeating it every time.